# Multiple Next Page Links on Same Page

Tags: python, web-scraping

In python, how would you handle in a web scrape if the next page link shows up twice on the same page and you only want to grab one of them after you scrape the page?

Example https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?groups=top_100&sort=user_rating,desc&ref_=adv_prv

Next page shows at the top and bottom of the list.

Comment: Help us to help you - Please improve your question, so that we can reproduce your issue easily. Take a minute to check - How to create [mcve] Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, find the section that contains the element you want:

```
movies_list = driver.find_element('xpath', '//div[contains(@class, "lister-item mode-advanced")]')

next_page = movies_list.find_element('xpath', './/div[contains(@class, "lister-page-next next-page")]')
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75885832/getting-to-next-page-in-beautiful-soup-specific-example?noredirect=1#comment133858148_75885832) try to select your element more specific. Instead of using [`.find_all()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#calling-a-tag-is-like-calling-find-all) or [`.select()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) that will give you a `ResultSet`, you could slice to one element of course or pick one by index,

```
movie_soup.select('.next-page')[0].get('href')
```

head for use of [`.find()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find) or `.select_one()` that will return only the first occurrence of element you searching for

```
movie_soup.select_one('.next-page').get('href')
```

Based on your initial code, what should always be provided in question, you could go with:

```
...
# Step 5: Parse the results object to movie_soup using the html parser.
movie_soup = BeautifulSoup(results.text, "html.parser")
nextpage = requests.get('https://www.imdb.com'+movie_soup.select_one('.next-page').get('href'))
  
# create soup for next url
nextsoup = BeautifulSoup(nextpage.content, 'html.parser')
...
```